# HTML5 input type range Value Bubbles

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I found something like this: '''https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/eYNQyPe'''
Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the reset button on the form. When I click reset value don't respond.

Comment: unable to view the source code at codepen please create a snippet here so anyone can debug in more detail

Comment: Please remember that our time is also limited as yours so you need to post specific questions with text code and all possible debug info here.

Comment: Sorry for that. Next time I add more information when I will have problem. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `output` element has no default value to reset to and the position is defined with inline css. Wrap the initial process into a function and call it after reseting.

Check this snippet:

```js
initRanges();
function initRanges() {
  const allRanges = document.querySelectorAll(".range-wrap");
  allRanges.forEach(wrap => {
    const range = wrap.querySelector(".range");
    const bubble = wrap.querySelector(".bubble");

    range.addEventListener("input", () => {
      setBubble(range, bubble);
    });
    setBubble(range, bubble);
  });
}

const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
const reset_btn = document.getElementById('reset_btn');

reset_btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  form.reset();
  initRanges();
})

function setBubble(range, bubble) {
  const val = range.value;
  const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
  const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
  const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 100) / (max - min));
  bubble.innerHTML = val;
  if (bubble.getAttribute('data-defval') === null) {
        bubble.setAttribute('data-defval', val);
  }

  // Sorta magic numbers based on size of the native UI thumb
  bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${8 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
}
```

```css
.range-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 3rem;
}
.range {
  width: 100%;
}
.bubble {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  top: -1px;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div class="range-wrap">
  <input type="range" class="range">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>

<div class="range-wrap">
  <input type="range" class="range" min="20" max="940">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>

<div class="range-wrap" style="width: 75%;">
  <input type="range" class="range" min="50" max="60" step="2">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>

<div class="range-wrap" style="width: 55%;">
  <input type="range" class="range" min="-20" max="20">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>
  <input type="button" id="reset_btn" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```